# Windows phone 8 plotting framework

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have used the open source core-plot in iOS and was wondering if there is any such  2d graph plotting framework present for windows phone.

Comment: i have used this in an iOS project of mine http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/ but could'nt find windows counterpart of it.

Answer (score 5):

There are many Charts & Data Visualization frameworks available for WP7/WP8. Many are availalbe commercially such as [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/chart.aspx), [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-phone/features/data-chart/), [ComponentArt](http://www.componentart.com/products/dv/wp7.aspx#charting), [VisiFire](http://www.visifire.com/documentation/Visifire_Documentation/Charts/Quick_Start/WP7/Your_First_Windows_Phone_Chart.htm) and many others. There are also free OSS charting frameworks such as [amCharts QuickCharts](https://github.com/ailon/amCharts-Quick-Charts), [Silverlight Toolkit for Desktop Charts](http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/silverlight-toolkit-charts-for-windows-phone-7/), [devMobile.net](http://devmobile.codeplex.com/) and others.

A year ago I downloaded all apps on the marketplace and figured out which frameworks are most commonly used. You can read the [full research here](http://justinangel.net/WindowsPhone7MarketplaceStatistics). Among the commercial options [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx) is the most commonly used which probably has something to do with it only costing 99$. Among the free options [amCharts](http://nuget.org/packages/amChartsQuickCharts) and [Silverlight Toolkit for Desktop](http://nuget.org/packages/SilverlightToolkit-DataViz) are the most used frameworks. Follow any of these links and you can get setup pretty quickly.

I've made this post a wiki so other control vendors can respectfully and insightfully edit this information.

Comment: yes i agree at what you say justin,but the thing is that after a little research i found that its better if we draw the graph as picture.As a picture is comprised of pixels after performing scaling on the pixels it will behave very much like a graph and System.Drawing namespace provides all the classes for drawing lines ,curves and circle which helps alot.